# Android - abort crash

Tags: java, android

I'm having this **crash** on android 10. I was unable to find any proper solution for this even though it's really complicated Stack trace to understand. Any Help will be appreciated. I'm using TensorFlow lite.

**Dependencies**

```
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.8.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.8.0'
```

Stack Trace:

````
**abort**

> *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.humbbles.imagenes <<<
> 
backtrace:

      #00  pc 000000000005f2d6 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+166)  
      #00  pc 000000000005f583  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__assert2+22)
      #00  pc 00000000001e75e5 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 00000000001e768d /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 00000000001e6171 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 00000000001e5cdf /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 00000000001e5ca7 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 00000000001e4921 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 00000000001cb3c9 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 00000000001c9823 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 00000000001c965b /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 00000000001b7d49 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 00000000001b7ae9 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
      #00  pc 000000000000c469 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/split_config.armeabi_v7a.apk!lib/armeabi-v7a/libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0x2198000)
    
    (Java_org_tensorflow_lite_NativeInterpreterWrapper_allocateTensors+92)
    
      #00  pc 00000000000582a1 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/oat/arm/base.odex (art_jni_trampoline+120)     
      #00  pc 00000000000d7bc5 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
      #00  pc 000000000042e89b /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+246)
      #00  pc 00000000000dffcb /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+194) 
      #00  pc 0000000000210be9 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+280)
      #00  pc 000000000020c52b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+774)
      #00  pc 0000000000425fb7 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+310) 
      #00  pc 00000000000d2994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so  (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
      #00  pc 0000000000b35354 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/oat/arm/base.vdex (org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.<init>+528)
      #00  pc 0000000000425b19  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+980)
      #00  pc 00000000000d2914 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)  
      #00  pc 0000000000b350b4  /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/oat/arm/base.vdex (org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapperExperimental.<init>)  
      #00  pc 0000000000425b19  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+980)
      #00  pc 00000000000d2914 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)  
      #00  pc 0000000000b35078  /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/oat/arm/base.vdex (org.tensorflow.lite.d.<init>+4)
      #00  pc 0000000000425b19 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+980) 
      #00  pc 00000000000d2914  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
      #00  pc 0000000000ada6f6 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/oat/arm/base.vdex (eb.f0.i+122)
      #00  pc 0000000000429173 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1118)
      #00  pc 00000000000d6594  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
      #00  pc 0000000000ad98f8 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/oat/arm/base.vdex (eb.f0$a.h+192)
      #00  pc 0000000000429173 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+1118)
      #00  pc 00000000000d6594  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
      #00  pc 0000000000b69be4 /data/app/com.humbbles.imagenes-QNprW9m5QjINKj69Syr81w==/oat/arm/base.vdex (za.a.run+80)
      #00  pc 00000000001ec465 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.4361200451203438240)+192)
      #00  pc 00000000001f0c49 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+124)
      #00  pc 00000000004182f9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+808)
      #00  pc 00000000000dc5a1 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
      #00  pc 00000000006d4199 /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+64)
      #00  pc 00000000006d6c2f /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1382)
      #00  pc 00000000004f0bcf  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+806)
      #00  pc 00000000000d7bc5 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
      #00  pc 000000000042e89b /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+246)
      #00  pc 00000000000dffcb /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+194)
      #00  pc 0000000000370377 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableconst&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54)
      #00  pc 000000000037167b /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeMethod(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, unsigned int)+850)
      #00  pc 000000000031e913  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Method_invoke(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*)+30)
      #00  pc 00000000000be82f  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+110)
      #00  pc 00000000008d590b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+114)  
      #00  pc 00000000008dc087  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+1814)
      #00  pc 00000000000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
      #00  pc 000000000042e89b /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+246)
      #00  pc 00000000000dffcb /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+194)
      #00  pc 0000000000370377 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable
     const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54)
      #00  pc 00000000003701b7 /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+290)
      #00  pc 00000000002bcaf1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+460)
      #00  pc 000000000007e351 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod(_jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...)+28)
      #00  pc 00000000000807ed  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, android::Vector<android::String8> const&, bool)+568)
      #00  pc 00000000000022ff  /system/bin/app_process32 (main+698)
      #00  pc 0000000000059919  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__libc_init+68)
      #00  pc 000000000000202f  /system/bin/app_process32 (_start_main+38)
      #00  pc 0000000000004456  <anonymous>
    ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be an assertion error happens after JNI function `Java_org_tensorflow_lite_NativeInterpreterWrapper_allocateTensors` has been called. According to the symbol name of this function, the relative Java method should be `org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.allocateTensors()`.

I thought you should **compile the TensorFlow things by yourself rather than use dependencies**, and **keep debug symbol** in it, you will get the actual **source-level line number** in the backtrace report next time, this will help you track down the bug.